# Can the leading bytes of an input stream be copied to another file without closing the input stream?

Tags: bash, stdin, head

I'm basically asking why:

```
head -c 2 > /tmp/first-two-bytes
cat /tmp/first-two-bytes -
```

doesn't copy the first two bytes of stdin to `/tmp/first-two-bytes` then dump the entire contents of stdin to stout.

[Edit] Just to be clear, here's what happens on my machine:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin Myles-Byrnes-iMac.local 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ echo "hello, world" | (head -c 2 > /tmp/first-two-bytes; cat /tmp/first-two-bytes -)
he$ cat /tmp/first-two-bytes 
he$
```

Comment: It does what you would expect in my case. What are you sending to stdin?

Comment: Works for me too, but see my response below.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how much output do you get if you have more than 8K of input?  I'm guessing head reads 4K or 8K of data, and that if you have enough input the cat will get some of it.

Comment: William: yup. Just tried it on a larger file and that's exactly what's happening. Darn

Answer (score 1):

Each byte in a stream can only be read once.  It is entirely possible that head could be implemented so that it reads only 2 bytes, but it is also possible that head could be implemented to read the entire stream and output only the first 2 bytes.  If the latter implementation is used, then stdout will be exhausted before cat ever sees any data.

If you want the functionality of head that is guaranteed to read exactly 2 bytes of data from the input stream and is maximally portable, you probably want to use dd.  Just replace `head -c 2` with `dd bs=2 count=1`

Comment: I'm seeing the behavior in the latter case

Comment: @quackingduck That would imply that your implementation of head is reading all of the data from the input stream, which is perfectly valid behavior for head.  If you want a program that reads exactly two characters from the stream, try: perl -e 'sysread STDIN, $v, 2; print $v'

Comment: Thanks william. I'm trying to avoid any dependencies on a scripting language as I intended to package a distribute the script.

Comment: @quackingduck  You can use dd: 'dd bs=2 count=1' will read exactly 2 bytes from the input stream, and is ubiquitous.

Answer (score 1):

Your commands do exactly what they should. Remember that a stream is not a file. Whatever is read from the stream, is removed from it. There's no rewinding (unless you implement it yourself using a buffer in your app - but it would be in the app, not a property of the stream). The first command reads 2 bytes from stdin. The other outputs the file from /tmp and the "entire contents of stdin" - but at the point it is called, the "entire contents" of stdin is already two bytes less than before the previous command was executed.

Comment: Right. That's exactly what I expect but it's not working for me :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this behavior on my machine. Maybe Darwin's head (pun intended) is somewhat different? I don't know if they use GNU coreutils or have their own. What does `head --version` say?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the following command, the behaviour is just as you describe:

```
$ echo "hello, world" | (head -c 2 > /tmp/first-two-bytes; cat /tmp/first-two-bytes -)
hello, world
$ cat /tmp/first-two-bytes
he$
```

Note that the last `$` is the prompt

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to write only the first two bytes from standard input into a special file and then print the entire input (including the first two bytes) to standard output.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
while read -r -n2 c2; do
    if [ ! -f tmp.txt ]; then
        echo $c2 > tmp.txt
    fi
    echo $c2
done < input.txt
```

Basically you first read the input into a variable, two bytes at a time, then write only the first two bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Manish. In this case I'm looking for a solution that does not read all of stdin into memory.

Comment: @quackingduck Updated it now so it reads the input line-by-line.

Comment: Hi Manish, thanks again for looking at this. I had considered using read but my concern is that it won't be binary safe. I really do want to read the first two bytes, not the first two chars. The program will receive binary files as input.

Comment: @quackingduck OK, I didn't know it was a binary file. I've updated my answer. You can use `read -r -n2` to read up to two bytes at a time.